# check if row exists with PDO

Tags: php

I am having trouble checking if a row exists to log someone in.
The password is salted in the db using the password+ the email
I am using PDO.

```
function is_valid_developer($username, $password)
{
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = sha(CONCAT(:password,(SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = :password))) AND developer = true';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $statement->execute();
    $count = $statement->fetchColumn();
    if ($count === 1)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else 
    {
        return FALSE;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated point...you shouldn't use sha1 for password hashes, it's incredibly weak.

Comment: @Lusitanian what should I use instead?

Comment: pbkdf2 with sha512 as a primitive or bcrypt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your subquery appears to be incorrect (see the `WHERE username = :password` clause), and will likely never return any results.  Further, using the same bound parameter twice is not supported in PDO (you use `:password` twice).  Besides that, you don't actually need a subquery at all; try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
WHERE username = :username
  AND password = sha(CONCAT(:password, email))
  AND developer;
```

Further, make sure you call `$statement->closeCursor()` after your call to `$statement->fetchColumn()`; leaving PDO statement cursors open after you are done with them may cause the database to fail on *all future queries*.

Comment: Weird, I've never had problems with not closing any of my statements.

Comment: @Mike That's why I said it *may* cause failure.  It depends on whether the cursors are server-side or emulated client-side; in the latter case, you cannot execute one query while enumerating the results of another.  Some PDO drivers also support automatic cursor destruction, which will close any open cursor when you execute a query.  However, to write portable and reliable code, it is good practice to close cursors when you are done with them.

Comment: Ahh yes that was a silly mistake with the :password. Thank you for the pointers, it is nice not to have to have subqueries. I did not realize not calling closeCursor could have adverse effects.